# Remote access to phpmyadmin from computer belongs to same LAN

Tags: linux, centos, php, remote-access

I have setup the myphpadmin on my CentOS 6.4 recently. I can access and login to the myphpadmin on my localhost. However, when I type http://[hostipaddr]/phpmyadmin on my other computer in the same LAN with the CentOS, the browser simply cannot access the page. Below are some of the current configuration. Anyone can help please......?

#### config.inc.php

```
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

#### phpmyadmin.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Furthermore, I can access the webpage that stored in the CentOS from my other computer without problems. After using wireshark and tcpdump, I found that the server (the Cent OS) keep resetting the connection. (192.168.1.106 is my other computer, 192.168.1.101 is my CentOS)

```
23:29:42.281473 IP 192.168.1.106.55999 > 192.168.1.101.webcache: Flags [S], seq    2559409090, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
23:29:42.281504 IP 192.168.1.101.webcache > 192.168.1.106.55999: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2559409091, win 0, length 0
```

I have disabled the iptables service on the CentOS already.

Comment: Please provide the solution you have found and the steps you took to find it in an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

OP Indicated he resolved this issue by:

It is because I have not configured the httpd.conf to allow the centos listen port 80 and 8080.

```
Listen 80 
Listen 8080
```